# CAPTCHA Bug: cannot see insert text box

Tags: bug, status-norepro, captcha

Yesterday and this morning I was trying to ask a question at StackOverflow.
System prompted me captcha form, but under the (funny) video I was unable to see the captcha insert text box; only the "I'm a Human Being" appared.

I got a screenshot, but upload of images failed here now.
After trying many times with different browsers, just 2 minutes ago my post went online, without requiring me captcha step again.

What's the problem?
Someone can explain me?

Comment: what web browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We occasionally see reports of this, but can't reproduce. I suspect proxy or firewall issues between you and us.

The page you want is https://stackoverflow.com/captcha

I suppose ReCaptcha could be down but that would be .. pretty fatal for a lot of the internet, us included.

Comment: Jeff Atwood in person, what an honour to talk with you! :-)  I tried with IE, Firefox and Chrome. Now it works, probably the problem is like what you say: temporary down of ReCaptcha or proxy limits on my line.  Thank you for the response!  Nando